# How to format a float number in Python in the current locale

Tags: python-3.x, internationalization

I want to format the float numbers in my Python app according to the current locale. The [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) states that one of the "available presentation types for floating point and decimal values" is:

> 'n'   Number. This is the same as 'g', except that it uses the current locale setting to insert the appropriate number separator characters.

But I can't make it work. This is how I tried:

```
$ unset LC_ALL
$ unset LANG
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
$ python3 -c "import locale; print (locale.getdefaultlocale())"
('de_DE', 'UTF-8')

$ python3 -c "print ('{0:.3n}'.format(3.14))"
3.14
```

I also tried with:

```
$ python3 -c "import locale; print (locale.str(3.14))"
3.14
$ python3 -c "import locale; print (locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14))"
3.14
```

I would expect all of these to print `3,14`, not `3.14`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You should set `LC_NUMERIC` to `de_DE`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.LC_NUMERIC

Answer (score 3):

Only setting the environment variables is not enough:

```bash
$ unset LC_ALL
$ unset LANG
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

You need to set LC_NUMERIC or LC_ALL explicitly with [locale.setlocale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) at the start of your Python script:

```bash
$ python3 -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8'); print(locale.str(3.14), '{0:.3n}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14), '{0:.3g}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14))"
3.14 3.14 3.14 3.14 3.14

$ python3 -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.UTF-8'); print(locale.str(3.14), '{0:.3n}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14), '{0:.3g}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14))"
3,14 3,14 3,14 3.14 3,14

$ python3 -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8'); print(locale.str(3.14), '{0:.3n}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14), '{0:.3g}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14))"
3.14 3.14 3.14 3.14 3.14

$ python3 -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8'); print(locale.str(3.14), '{0:.3n}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14), '{0:.3g}'.format(3.14), locale.format_string('%.2f', 3.14))"
3,14 3,14 3,14 3.14 3,14
```

Answer (score 1):

[`format_string()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.format_string) says "Formats a number val according to the current `LC_NUMERIC` setting."

If you are wanting to test numbers in different locales this is how you change the locale:

```py
import locale
# Change to German locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')
```

Using some of your examples, we have:

```py
number = 3.14
print(r'Expecting 3,14   Using %g')
print(locale.format_string('%g', number))

print(r'Expecting 3,14   Using %.2f')
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', number))

print(r'Expecting 3,14   Using locale.str()')
print(locale.str(number))
```

Output:

```bash
Expecting 3,14   Using %g
3,14
Expecting 3,14   Using %.2f
3,14
Expecting 3,14   Using locale.str()
3,14
```

Changing locale (back) to US

```py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US')
```

Now I get the following output:

```bash
Expecting 3.14   Using %g
3.14
Expecting 3.14   Using %.2f
3.14
Expecting 3.14   Using locale.str()
3.14
```